# in CMake, What's the difference between command SUBDIRS() and ADD_SUBDIRECTORY()

Tags: c++, build, cmake, build-automation

in CMake, What's the difference between command SUBDIRS() and ADD_SUBDIRECTORY()

when i read PoDoFo src, i found some CMakeLists.txt use SUBDIRS some use ADD_SUBDIRECTORY,
I am novice! thanks!

Comment: subdirs is deprecated, use add_subdirectory

Comment: @Anycorn That should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

subdirs is deprecated, use add_subdirectory

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-next/command/subdirs.html

Answer (score 7):

From the [CMake Mailing List](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-August/015739.html):

> `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY()` processes the subdir at the time it is called, whereas `SUBDIRS()` pushes the dirs onto a list which is processed at the end of the current CMakeLists file - this is the old behaviour and some vars are initialized 'out of order', or at least in unexpected order.

(...)

> So, if you set variables in the parent directory they will not be seen in the subdir when `SUBDIRS()` is used.

Furthermore it is recommended in [CMake's Documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/subdirs.html) that you should use `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY()` instead, as `SUBDIRS()` is deprecated.